# D3D9 Render to Texture with Multisampling

Tags: directx

I want to render to a texture using multisampling, then render that to the back buffer using a textured quad (passing it through a pixel shader.) Everything works fine without multisampling but I just can't figure out how to set it up to use multisampling.

I tried CreateDepthStencilSurface() but I don't really know what to do with that surface, or if tat's even what I should be doing.

Please help.

PS - I'm using DX9, Win32 and C++

Answer (score 3):

You can't, not directly anyway. Here is the regular workaround:

1. Create a multisample render target using [IDirect3DDevice9::CreateRenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Create a simple texture
3. Render to your multisample render target
4. Use [IDirect3DDevice9::StretchRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to blit your multisampled content into one of the surfaces of your texture
5. Now proceed to use that texture as planned.

Comment: I would add a precision: *2. Create a simple texture with the same parameters (width, heigth, format) than the render target*

Answer (score 0):

-Create a RenderTarget and DepthStencilSurface - these must have the same multisampling options set (same SampleDescription)

-Set the DepthStencilSurface as your DepthStencilView

-DepthStencilSurface must have at least as much resolution as the RenderTarget

-Highest SampleDescription-setting most card's support as of today is 8 Samples and Quality 32

-To blit the RenderTarget use StretchRect on DX9 and ResolveSubresource on DX10 an DX11